# How to keep dovecot from creating .imap directories if IMAP is disabled?

Tags: configuration, dovecot, imap

Since several years and through the last three Debian distributions, I am running dovecot as a POP3 server. In general, it works as expected, and I'm happy with it.

However, there is one little issue which I have ignored in the past, but now would like to understand. As described above, I use only the POP3 part of dovecot, and I do not use the IMAP part. dovecot nevertheless creates an .imap directory in the respective users' home directories.

This is not a show stopper, but I'd like to understand why it happens and how to prevent it.

This is my configuration:

```
root@odysseus /home/usr # dovecot -n
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
# OS: Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 x86_64 Debian 10.4
# Hostname: odysseus.example.com
listen = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mail_location = mbox:~
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
pop3_lock_session = yes
protocols = " pop3"
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/tls/pop-ssl.omeganet.de.crt
ssl_cipher_list = DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
root@odysseus /home/usr #
```

Of course, I have noticed that there is a `namespace inbox { ... }` block, but I always thought that this part of the configuration would relate only to IMAP and would not be relevant in my case. Furthermore, due to the configuration, each user's "inbox" is a single file which is located directly in the home directories, so I can't imagine what the .imap subdirectories are good for. A typical user's home directory looks like that:

```
root@odysseus /home/usr/user11 # dir
total 193K
drwxr-xr-x  6 user11 mailusrs   10 2020-05-31 00:04 .
drwx--x--x 13 root   root       13 2020-03-24 21:22 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user11 mailusrs  220 2019-04-18 06:12 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 user11 mailusrs 3.5K 2019-04-18 06:12 .bashrc
drwx------  3 user11 mailusrs    5 2020-05-30 23:08 compile
drwxr-xr-x  6 user11 mailusrs    7 2020-05-31 00:04 .imap
-rw-------  1 user11 mailusrs  536 2020-05-30 23:57 inbox  <<<<<<------ This is the actual inbox file
drwx------  4 user11 mailusrs   33 2020-05-30 23:08 tests
-rw-r--r--  1 user11 mailusrs  807 2019-04-18 06:12 .profile
drwx------  3 user11 mailusrs   55 2020-05-30 23:08 www-data
root@odysseus /home/usr/user11 #
```

So why does dovecot create those .imap subdirectories?